# Generic Exception e catch overwrites specific exception Java

Tags: java, web-services, exception, try-catch

I am throwing an exception when error is generated in `throw new ResponseError(new DefaultResponse)` and it looks fine when I output the message but then it gets overwritten by `catch(Exception e)` block. What can I do ignore the generic `catch` if there's an error generated above it?

This is my web service

```
@DELETE
@SecureIt
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/training-courses/{emptcId}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Delete training course",
              response = DefaultResponse.class,
                authorizations = {
                    @Authorization(
                        value="Bearer" 
                    )
                })
public Response deleteTrainingCourse(@ApiParam(value = "Employee Training Course Id", required = true) @PathParam("emptcId") Integer emptcId,
                                     @Context ContainerRequestContext crc)
throws ResponseError {
    ClsConnectionData connection = null;

    try 
    {
        String mToken = crc.getProperty("token").toString();
        connection = new ClsConnectionData(mToken);

        StatementWrapper sw = new StatementWrapper(connection)
            .createCall(" {CALL j2_employee.delete_training_course(?,?)} ")
            .bind(1,emptcId)
            .registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR)
            .invoke();

        VoidResult voidResult = (VoidResult)sw.getSingleResultClass(2,VoidResult.class);

        if(voidResult.errorGenerated()) {
            throw new ResponseError(new DefaultResponse(ErrorCodes.DRIVEERROR.code(),
                                                        ResponseType.ERROR.getType(),
                                                        voidResult.getMessage(),
                                                        null));
        //At this point we are throwing the exception
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //At the end this error is thrown
        System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
        throw new ResponseError(e,true);
    }
    finally{
      connection.disconnect();
    }

    DefaultResponse dt = new DefaultResponse("0",
                                            ResponseType.SUCCESS.getType(),
                                            "",
                                            null); 
    return Response.ok(dt).build();
}
```

Comment: I don't get your issue, in the catch(Exception) block you are re-throwing the exception, isn't that enough ? You can't bypass the catch(Exception) block other than removing it ? Or maybe in the catch block symply writing "throw e;" would be enough since the exception would not be altered ?

Comment: ..is `ResponseError` *not* an (a descendant of `java.lang.`) `Exception` ? ...since you don't `return` but `throw` (!) it... so the `catch (Exception e)`...is absolutely predictable!

Comment: @SébastienPalud if voidResult.errorGenerated() will eventually be false then catch(Exception e) will not catch the exception. I want to catch(Exception e) if no previous exception has been thrown. The first exception new DefaultResponse(...) is very specific and gets overwritten underneath...

Comment: Please don't catch `Exception` or `Throwable` directly. Catch the exact `Exception` class that you expected to be thrown (let's say `IOException`). Then you will have clear understanding what can go wrong and how you fix it.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk : ..then you have to catch your type of exception (`ResponseError`) **first**! ...and *then* catch the more generalized... ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch(Exception e) catches any Exception of type Exception.class or a subclass from Exception that is thrown in the try-block. So, also the exception you throw yourself in the try-block. If ResponseError is a sublcass of Exception, then it will be caught as well.

You could throw the ResponseError outside the try. If you define voidResult before the try and check for the errorGenerated after, you will no longer have that problem. You get something like this:

```
VoidResult voidResult = null;
try {
    // some code getting to a voidResult
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // some code dealing with this eception
}
if (voidResult != null && voidResult.errorGenerated()) {
    // throw ResponseError
}
```

Or you should make sure the catch(Exception e) doesn't catch all exceptions, but only more specific ones. It depends on the implementation code if that's an options. Say if your implementation-code only throws ConnectionExceptions (to name an example), you could catch (ConnectionException) instead of Exception. If ResponseError is a subclass of Exception, but isn't a subclass of ConnectionException, it will no longer be caught.

You could also do something like:

```
DefaultResponse errorResponse = null
try {
    // some code
    if (voidResult.errorGenerated()) {
        errorResponse = new DefaultResponse();
    }
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // deal with error
}
if (errorResponse != null) {
    throw new ResponseError////
```

As last you could try to see if the Exception you caught is your own Exception and rethrow it.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof ResponseError && ((ResponseError) e).getCode.equals(myCode)) {
    throw e;
    else { // etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a special handling of general exceptions in distinction to custom ones,...

> ..then you have to catch  ... (the custom) exceptions first! ...and then catch the more generalized... ones.

Like:

```
// ...
catch (ResponseError respErr) {
    System.out.println("ResponseError e = " + respErr);
    // re-throw! - no "new"!
    throw respErr;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // but as @mndeveci mentioned: no good style!
    System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
    throw new ResponseError(e, true);
}
// ...
```